# Using ELF files compiled on WSL in Windows

Tags: debugging, arm, embedded, cross-compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As the title suggests i am compiling embedded programs on WSL.

I want be able to use these ELF containers in Segger's Ozone debugging software. This software cant resolve the linked source file since its an UNIX file path.
So i want to know if its possible to change the path definitions in the ELF container to Windows specific ones.

As i can see Ozone is for example trying to load something in `/mnt/c/Users/...` and the file can be found on the same path but as `c:\Users\...`.

Comment: Regardless of OS, you should probably use project-relative paths rather than absolute ones?

Comment: Did you try using the various path adjustment schemes provided by Ozone for resolving this kind of problems ? see section `5.14.3    File Path Resolution Sequence` of the [Ozone User Guide](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/UM08025_Ozone.pdf).  If building your bare-metal software under Linux is not a strong requirement, or is not a requirement at all, your problem can alternatively be solved by building your executable using an [Arm GCC toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain)  built for Windows.

Comment: @Frant Thanks! Ozone path substitutions are working like a charm!

Im using it for two days now, still alot to figure out.